# Cocoa Touch Class can't find default Group or Target for my project

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm going through the basics and following the RoadMap iOS *Start Developing iOS Apps Today* guide. In the Tutorial: Storyboards chapter under the heading [Create Custom View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW6), it explains how to create a new Cocoa Touch Class called AddToDoItemViewController.

Step 8 explains how the save location will default to my project directory, the Group option will default to my app name, and in the Target section, my app will be selected.

However, none of these settings are defaulting for me: [image: Creating Cocoa Touch Class file]

And when I click create, my files are added outside of my Project. [image: .h and .m files added]

I can't work out how to change any of the settings when creating these files. Could anyone shed any light on the issue for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your not adding your files in the folder that the project navigator is displaying.  When you created the Xcode project it made a project folder called TodoList and inside it is your .xcodeproj file and next to that is another folder called TodoList.  That is the folder that you want to add your classes to.

Comment: Okay, I selected the folder ToDoList inside ToDoList, but my Group and Target are still blank, and my files still get added outside the Project. Am I missing something seriously important? http://i.imgur.com/NPXlNxi.png

Comment: Interesting, how are you adding the files?  Are you creating a new file? Right clicking when todoList folder is selected?

Comment: I've been hitting File > New > File... I just tried right clicking the ToDoList folder, but the target and group were still blank. I've been able to incorporate the .m and .h files with my main folder, but they're showing up with an A next to them rather than an M. Does this look correct to you? http://i.imgur.com/MeA5ADf.png

Comment: Those A & M markings are for the git repo the that it creates. A means added and M means modified.  That doesn't have anything to do with Xcode setup though that's just the git.  It sounds strange to me that it's not finding the group but sometimes Xcode just screws up like that.  If you choose the folder you want the files to go in, the next time you add a file does it find it?  And yes that all looks ok

Answer (score 0):

When you create new file, Xcode will use the place where is active (highlighted with blue color) in Project Navigator.

Since you are viewing project top, then your file is created there, but you can change the file path and belonging group before you click create.

If you have already created in wrong place, that can be corrected:

1. Move you newly create files in right place by Finder.
2. The files moved in step1 will be in red color in project navigator since Xcode can't locate it. Open Utilities and select File Inspector tab, click the little folder icon (below Location, above Full Path), and choose the new file location.
3. Rearrange your group if necessary.